# Supercaviating Aquatic Creature

Tags: biology, xenobiology

Ever since I watched [this video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercavitation#:%7E:text=Supercavitation%20is%20the%20use%20of,to%20an%20entire%20underwater%20vessel.) theorizing about how Aquaman could dislocate in water at supersonic speeds via [supercavitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL0F_F1k7kw&pp=ugMICgJwdBABGAE%3D) I got interested in implementing this hability in some sort of aquatic creatures, and I hypothesized if some sort of natural hydrophobic coating or by twitching their muscles really fast, like shaking from cold, but faster microscopic vibrations as I read that vibrations could generate this effect, could any of these work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a marine animal on our planet which makes use of supercavitation:

[Behold the Mantis Shrimp](https://www.si.edu/newsdesk/snapshot/behold-mantis-shrimp#:%7E:text=It%20kills%20its%20prey%20by,in%20a%20process%20called%20supercavitation.)

[image]

Now, the mantis shrimp doesn't use supercavitation in locomotion but rather in its "punches" when attacking/cracking open prey. But it shows that it is actually more than only theoretically possible.

Answer (score 2):

By magic - Yes

By science - Not really.
Making cavitation buble will give You nothing. You need propelant like rocket. Is hardly belivable to squeze water in internal organ (like squids) to release it with speed higher than speed of sound in water. Maybe can make some kind of internel organ where water is cavitated and throved out but doing this without detonate or cooking this animal need so much strong muscles and heavy body that any thrust even lots higher than speed of sound will not give long distance run. But for meter or two - maybe.